# Handle nested JsonArrays without key when parsing JSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I am new to Java and programming in general, and I am making a simple API parser using Jackson and GSON.
Here is an example of the API JSON (I have no idea why it is pasting inline).

```
{
  "Matches":[
    {
      "actualStartTime":"2019-04-06T13:23:12.767",
      "tournamentLevel":"Playoff",
      "postResultTime":"2019-04-06T13:26:57.89",
      "description":"Quarterfinal 4",
      "matchNumber":4,
      "scoreRedFinal":77,
      "scoreRedFoul":9,
      "scoreRedAuto":9,
      "scoreBlueFinal":83,
      "scoreBlueFoul":0,
      "scoreBlueAuto":12,
      "teams":[
        {
          "teamNumber":4041,
          "station":"Red1",
          "dq":false
        },
        {
          "teamNumber":2523,
          "station":"Red2",
          "dq":false
        },
        {
          "teamNumber":3930,
          "station":"Red3",
          "dq":false
        },
        {
          "teamNumber":172,
          "station":"Blue1",
          "dq":false
        },
        {
          "teamNumber":4564,
          "station":"Blue2",
          "dq":false
        },
        {
          "teamNumber":6172,
          "station":"Blue3",
          "dq":false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My parser works fine up until the Array "teams".  I am having trouble getting it to re-iterate over the array.  Here is the code I am using to parse the outer level.  It just prints the whole String as is for the inner arrays (which I do not want).

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
            if (field.getValue().isArray()) {
                JsonObject ac = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();
                JsonArray ad = ac.getAsJsonArray(field.getKey());
                Iterator<JsonElement> it = ad.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    JsonObject a = it.next().getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonFactory factory2 = new JsonFactory();
                    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper(factory2);
                    JsonNode rootNode2 = mapper2.readTree(String.valueOf(a));
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator2 = rootNode2.fields();
                    while (fieldsIterator2.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field2 = fieldsIterator2.next();
                        // Do stuff with field2.getKey() and field2.getValue()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So basically field2 is sometimes an array.  My goal a way to convert field2 into its own JsonObject or string then parsing it again, or even better one iterator that handles that, but I have tried different combinations of fields and arrays, and end up confusing myself and getting nowhere.  I am really stuck, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will the json string always follow this kind of format?

Comment: Yes it will follow that format, but the keys will change.

Comment: will the key names ever change? for e.g. "Matches", "actualStartTime", "scoreBlueAuto", "teams", etc. or do you mean the actual values will be different? Will there always be an array called "Matches" where each item in the array has the same structure? And each item in the "items" array will have the same structure as well?

Comment: Yes, the key names will often change.  For example, teams could become alliances, and Matches would become schedule.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON format is fixed then you can use JSONPath to parse the JSON with regex and extract the right piece of information.

Say for example from the above JSON, if you have to get all the teams we could just use

```
"$.Matches[*].teams[*]"
```

Below links will help you to understand about josnpath.

1. https://jsonpath.com/
2. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath